# CSS fixed size margin only between elements

Tags: css, flexbox

This keeps coming up on certain projects and I wanted to see if anyone may have a better solution.

Essentially, I'm trying to have a group of div elements of which all have an equal amount of spacing between them but not around. **The snippet below is an example of what I'm looking for, my hope is someone may have a cleaner solution.**

My question here is if anyone has a better solution that may use less css or less HTML elements. The important things to maintain:

- Localization compliant - Since we aren't using margin left or right there aren't any weird localization issues in rtl
- Alignment - It shouldn't size to the whole window if it doesn't need to but it should wrap if needed. (see example)
- Spacing - Should be a fixed amount of space between the elements

If you have any ideas I'd love to hear them!

```css
        body {
            background-color: black;
            padding: 30px;
        }
        .inner {
            overflow: hidden;
            margin: 20px 0px;
        }
        .innerMargin {
            background-color: white;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            margin: -10px;
        }
        .innerMargin > div {
            flex: 0 0 20px;

            background-color: red;
            margin: 10px;
            height: 20px;
            width: 20px;
        }
        .fixedWidth {
            width: 180px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="inner">
        <div class="innerMargin">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner fixedWidth">
        <div class="innerMargin">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Padding or margin? Your title says "padding" but I see margin everywhere else

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're aiming for but possibly try something like `margin:20px` on the inner elements and `margin:-20px` on the outer so that the leftmost and rightmost items appear to hug the sides.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob Corrected the padding in the title

Comment: @chris22smith I think what you're suggesting is exactly what can be seen in my code snippet. My hope was someone may have a better solution that may not require three layers of divs.

Comment: did "justify-content: space-around;" doesn't resolve your issue? :-/

Comment: @k2snowman69 so your example snippet is giving you the desired output but you are looking for optimizing? is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @kukkuz yep precisely! The goal is finding a better more optimal solution. I know it's a bit different than usual questions but I figure it still an important question to know if a more optimal version exists.

Comment: @MarouenMhiri So justify-content: space around gives a variable amount of space between the elements where I want a fixed amount of space between the elements. Small but important difference as it changes the minimum content size by the size of the buffer (which has cascading effects upon flexbox layouts and scrolling elements)

Comment: @k2snowman69 I couldn't think of any better solution... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it should be noted this is trivial with CSS Grid.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 20px/repeat(auto-fit, 20px);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 20px;
}

.container div {
  background-color: red;
}

.fixed-width {
  width: 180px;
}

.container > div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container fixed-width">
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen here](https://codepen.io/skube/pen/WdeyNN)

Comment: It's hilarious, I was just about to add this exact comment! Mind if I make a few edits to clean it up along with add a link to https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid as it's not currently supported in all browsers?

Comment: But making this the suggested answer as, well, in the future it will be :-)

Comment: Nice! It can't come too soon ;) (feel free to edit as you see fit)

Comment: Here's a fun addition to this question... what if you didn't actually know the width of each box. Grid is great at, well a grid layout, but I think in that scenario you would probably want to go back to a flex layout like my original comment. I've tried for a bit to get grid to work for auto sized items and I just can't seem to get it to work. Wondering if you know something I don't :-)

Answer (score 1):

A pretty quick way to accomplish this if you're just dealing with a row/column is to use a last-child pseudoselector to override margin to 0. Like so:

```css
.column-item {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.column-item:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
beginning
<div id="column">
<div class="column-item"></div>
<div class="column-item"></div>
<div class="column-item"></div>
<div class="column-item"></div>
<div class="column-item"></div>
<div class="column-item"></div>
<div class="column-item"></div>
</div>
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know you will *always* have 5 boxes in the `fixedwidth` box, you could do something like:

**HTML (Slim)**

```
.container
  - 5.times do
    .box

.container.container--thinner
  - 15.times do
    .box
```

**CSS (SCSS)**

```
$width : 36;
body {background-color: #000;}
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  width: $width + em;

  .box {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    background-color: red;
  }

  &--thinner {
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: $width/2 + em;

    .box {
      margin-bottom: 2em;
      &:nth-of-type(5n) {
        margin-right: 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/skube/pen/RgMBRQ?editors=1100)

Comment: True but I would argue that this solution is worse reason being is that it only works with distinct intervals binding your HTML and CSS together. The solution I provided allows the HTML to be whatever it wants and the all the actual layout is done via CSS keeping the separation of layers.